[OfficeParser]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users
I am trying to extract text from any document uploaded by a user, this is my extractFromFile function.
import { parseOfficeAsync } from "officeparser";

export async function extractTextFromFile(filePath: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const data = await parseOfficeAsync(filePath);
    return data.toString();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return "File has not been parsed";
  }
}

Below is where I am calling this extractTextFromFile function:
const handleFileUpload = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
    }

    // Extract text from the uploaded file
    const extractedText = await extractTextFromFile(req.file.path);
    console.log("extracted text: " + extractedText);
    return extractedText;
}

This is me defining the route for the file upload:
router.post("/upload", upload.single('file'), handleFileUpload)
Mind you I have already installed officeparser with
npm i officeparser
Now, I am getting this error below:

[OfficeParser]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My documents\Programming\MERN\Quizme\server\uploads\a3428f2277a7475f4e407753ed5c130a' -> 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My documents\Programming\MERN\Quizme\server\officeParserTemp\tempfiles\172189849682200000.uploads\a3428f2277a7475f4e407753ed5c130a'
extracted text: File has not been parsed

in my console.
Upon this error, I have confirmed in my source directory and the uploads directory is being created where the uploaded file is being saved. looking at the error message, OfficeParser is trying to copy the uploaded file into a temporary file in a temporary directory, but only a part of those directories were created, not all.
....\server\officeParserTemp\tempfiles\ gets created when an upload request is sent. but 172189849682200000.uploads\ is not present so is the file into which the uploaded file has to be copied into.
I tried creating the 172189849682200000.uploads\ folder manually but this does not work either.
This is what I have tried so far.
I will be glad if you could also suggest other parsing libraries I can use in my nodejs project.

please try v5 of officeparser@5.0.0 which does not require storing any temp files on the storage. It does all the processing in memory. It should fix your problem. Please let me know here or create an issue in the officeparser git repo if it does not.
